# How to bring contacts up to send a text

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I have an application that defines a word and then sends the definition via SMS. The problem is that the user has to type in a phone number. I was thinking that perhaps the app should bring up the contacts list, so the user can select a contact which the user can then send the message to that contact. Here is my code for the SMSActivity:

```
public class SMSActivity extends Activity 
{

String APPTAG = "SMSTransmit";

//Private static strings:
private final static String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
private final static String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

private Button btnSend;
private Button btnExit; 
private Button btnClear;
private EditText etPhoneNumber;
private EditText etUserMessage;

//Private BroadcastReceiver member variables:
private SMSDispatchReceiver sendReceiver = null;
private SMSReceiptReceiver receiptReceiver = null;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String definiedWord = null; 
    if (extras != null) 
    {
        definiedWord = extras.getString("DEFINITION"); 
    }
    else 
    {
        definiedWord = "None"; 
    }

    Log.d("recievedAGAIN", definiedWord);
    Log.v(APPTAG, "MainActivity: onCreate() called");

    //Create a new broadcast receiver for sending the SMS
    sendReceiver = new SMSDispatchReceiver();

    //Create a new broadcast receiver for receipt of the send SMS 
    receiptReceiver = new SMSReceiptReceiver();

    //Register the new receivers (as new IntentFiler() objects):
    registerReceiver(sendReceiver, new IntentFilter(SENT));
    registerReceiver(receiptReceiver, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    //Get the view objects:
    btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
    btnExit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
    etPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNumber);
    etUserMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMessage);

    //Disable the soft keyboard (this is only in general):
    InputMethodManager inMethodMgr =                                                                (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inMethodMgr.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(etPhoneNumber.getWindowToken(), 0);
    inMethodMgr.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(etUserMessage.getWindowToken(), 0);

    //Set the hint for the EditText boxes:
    etPhoneNumber.setHint("Enter phone number (Default = 5556)");
    etUserMessage.setHint(definiedWord);

    //Create an click event listener for the Send button (OnClickListener):
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            String strMessage = null;
            String strNumber = null;

            //Get the phone number from the EditText box:
            strNumber = etPhoneNumber.getText().toString();

            //Check the phone number:
            if (strNumber.length() <= 0) 
            {

                //No phone number, then get the default (5556):
                strNumber = SMSProperties.getPhoneNumber();
            }


            //Get the message from the EditText box:
            strMessage = etUserMessage.getText().toString();

            //Check the message contains some content:
            if (strMessage.length() > 0) 
            {

                //Sent the SMS to the phone number 
                sendSMS(strNumber, strMessage);  

            } else 
            {

                //Warn the user and reset the focus / hint:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No message text! Please      enter some text for the SMS!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                etUserMessage.setHint("Enter message text here . . . ");
                etUserMessage.requestFocus();

            }

        }
    });



    //Create an click event listener for the Clear button (OnClickListener):
    btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Clear the appropriate EditText box:
            if (etUserMessage.isFocused()) {

                //Clear the text in the user message EditText box:
                etUserMessage.setText("");

                //Set the hint in the user message EditText box:
                etUserMessage.setHint("Enter message text here . . . ");

            } else if (etPhoneNumber.isFocused()) {

                //Clear the text in the phone number EditText box:
                etPhoneNumber.setText("");

                //Set the hint in the phone number EditText box:
                etPhoneNumber.setHint("Enter phone number (Default = 5556)");
            }
        }
    });



    //Create an click event listener for the Exit button (OnClickListener):
    btnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            //Finish the activity:
            //NOTE: As this is the main activity it will cause onDestroy() to be called!
            finish();
        }
    });

}



//Method to send an SMS message to another device:
private void sendSMS(String strNum, String strMsg)
{                   
    //TODO: Create a pending intent for the SMSDistatchReceiver (SENT):
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("SENT"), 0);

    //TODO: Create a pending intent for the SMSReceiptReceiver (DELIVERED):
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("DELIVERED"), 0);
    //Get a default SmsManager object:
    SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();

    //TODO: Send the SMS using the SmsManager:  
    smsMgr.sendTextMessage(strNum, null, strMsg, sentPI, deliveredPI);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

consider contact is a button to bring up the contact list

```
contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
            @Override
            public void onClick(View g) {
                Intent q = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(q, 1001);  

            }
        });
```

and to handle the result (which is referenced by 1001) use this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);  

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  
            // getting the URI from result for further working
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {


              String  id =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

              String hasPhone =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));



              if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
              Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( 
                              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
                              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id, 
                              null, null);
                    phones.moveToFirst();
                      //this string will hold the contact number
                      String cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                      //this string will hold the contact name
                      String cName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                  }

            }} 
        }
```